# Delphi + DataSnap: How to invoke more than one class?

Tags: delphi, datasnap

fellas,

There is a information about Delphi and Datasnap that I still couldn't find or figure out... Imagine that I want to put all my inteligence in the Server layer. In this case, of course, I will use the Object Orientation concepts, creating a large number of classes, each one with it's own methods and attributes. Since in every example I see a client retrive information about only one server class, I wonder: Is it possible, anyway, to work with more than one class, or am I limited to only one class containing a bunch of different methods?

Could you guys understand?

Thanks for any help,

Paulo

Answer (score 1):

There is no useful answer yet so I decided to give one. 
There is a TWebDataModule in most of the given example if not you can go datamodule where you drop the DSServer component. There you will find DSServerClass(1) which is responsible to expose the server methods of one class.

So What you can do is to drop(create) another **DSServerClass** to the module. Now in ObjectInsepecor go to **properties -> Server** set the default server which might be of name DSServer1(default one in the example). go to **Events --> OnGetClass** double click so that handler will be assigned to the same.

Now
  you can write like this(you can see the existing one of the first DSServerclass1 for reference)
  set the `PersistentClass := ServerMethodunit1.user;`  Here **user** is the class name which methods need to expose.

Answer (score 0):

A useful design pattern for this scenario - many business classes, which have to communicate with an "external" client application over a communication layer - is **[Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)**.

> A facade is an object that provides a simplified interface to a larger
>   body of code, such as a class library.

To the client side, the facade exposes methods which in turn call instances of your business classes.

This also has the advantage that your business model classes can evolve while the API remains stable.

Also you should consider **[Data Transfer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)**, a design pattern which avoids exposing internal object classes and data structures for better encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem for a DataSnap server to expose multiple classes to a client. Just have a look into the samples. Even the "Basic" sample server exposes three server classes.